# How to add properties to <a> in CSS

Tags: html, css, properties, tags

For every individual `<a>` tag I have on my website I have to add the properties `"target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"`. It doesn't work when I put this in my CSS stylesheet however:

```
a {
target: "_blank";
rel: "noopener noreferrer";
}
```

It says the properties are unknown, which can't make sense because they are recognized and work when I put them within the actual tag.

Comment: CSS cannot be used to add any old properties. CSS is only for defining style properties.  Target and rel are properties of the anchor tag not styles. They cannot be added with CSS.

Comment: I don't think it is possible with CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Only styling can be added with css not html attributes. Eg
 You can replace below inline css style with external css
     <a href="#" style="color:blue">

    to
    <a href="#">
     a{
        color: blue;
        }

  Whatever is there in style attribute inline can be replaced with css. 
         <a href="#" target="_blank"> 
  This is target attribute and it cannot be replaced using css. Only 
   inline css using style can be replaced with external css.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using JavaScript.

```
<script>
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    
        for (var i = links.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            links[i].setAttribute("target", "_blank");
            links[i].setAttribute("rel", "noopener noreferrer");
        }
</script>
```

Insert this at the bottom of the html documents containing links. Or you could save it as a file and include the script in the header of your HTML documents.